# use list for function arguments in python

Tags: python, list, loops

I cant get my head around how to do this.  I have a nested list, which I want to use as function arguments.

The function.

```
pi.bb_i2c_zip(SDA, [4, address, 2, 7,18, {commands} ])
```

I would like to loop through the list so the end result is like below.

```
NestedList = [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],[2,0,2,0,2,0],[0,0,1,1,0,0]]

pi.bb_i2c_zip(SDA, [4, address, 2, 7,18, 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 ])
pi.bb_i2c_zip(SDA, [4, address, 2, 7,18, 2,0,2,0,2,0 ])
pi.bb_i2c_zip(SDA, [4, address, 2, 7,18, 0,0,1,1,0,0 ])
```

If i try using this;

```
for i in NestedList:
  pi.bb_i2c_zip(SDA, [4, address, 2, 7,18, i ])
```

I get this errror;
TypeError: an integer or string of size 1 is required

This is because the function is expecting bytes and the loop above is placing in an actual list of bytes.. E.g. `pi.bb_i2c_zip(SDA, [4, address, 2, 7,18,[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]])`

in summary, how can I place;
`1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8`
into the function and not this
`[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]`

Comment: `pi.bb_i2c_zip(SDA, [4, address, 2, 7,18, *i ])`

Answer (score 4):

You have to unpack the list first.

```
for i in NestedList:
  pi.bb_i2c_zip(SDA, [4, address, 2, 7,18, *i ])
```

Otherwise, your list argument is just another nested list. The `*` unpacking is more efficient (though possibly less clear) than `[4, address, 2, 7, 18] + i`. Unpacking also works with any iterable `i`, whereas `+` requires conversion of `i` to a list (i.e., `[...] + list(i)`).

Comment: "The * unpacking is more efficient (though possibly less clear)" Personally looks clear to me. I would probably just rename `i` to something more meaningful.

Comment: I very much like `[..., *i]`, but I don't think it's obvious at first glance that prefixing a `*` will expand the iterable to its elements. It's certainly a good idiom once you adjust to it, though.